# What happens to a Facebook Page Account after register into a Facebook developer?

Tags: facebook

My team currently developing apps for a client that have a Page Account, and now the client ask us what would happen to their Page account if registered as a developer and manage an app that my team being working on.

Is there any issue or effect upgrading to developer from Page account? 
And in this case, what would happen to that Page account after registered as a facebook developer?

Comment: You can not use page accounts for developing. Each person developing must use their own personal account. No fake accounts, no “company accounts”. (If you are looking for a way to manage apps that a company owns, look into the Business Manager.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response. Well, if i'm using A personal account (to upgrade as developer), after registered as a developer, is there any new capabilities (or changes) when i'm registered as a developer compared to my previous account (Personal Account before registered as developer)?

Comment: Well for one thing, you can create apps after you registered as a developer :-)